# How to center align 2 views?

Tags: android, android-layout

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_blue"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_viewPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_view" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_viewPost"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="View post"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/socialShare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@color/bg_light_grey"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_socialShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_post" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ic_socialShare"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Share with others"
            android:textColor="@color/text_dark_grey"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**In graphical layout:**

[image]

**On actual device:**

[image]

In the graphical layout it looks the way I wanted, but on actual device its completely different.

In the 1st Relative Layout the ImageView and TextView are not at all aligned.

In the 2nd Relative Layout it looks like the TextView is bottom aligned to the ImageView.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this instead of pair `ImageView-TextView`

```
    <TextView
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_viewPost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="View post"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:gravity= "center" from both the textViews and check.it should solve the problem as you are already using gravity center in linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your TextView and ImageView.

```
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```